# Ocultar teclado al hacer clic en cualquier parte de la Activity

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

Lo primero decir que he visto las preguntas que hay sobre este tema pero ninguna respuesta me ha servido, así que he decidido abrir una nueva.

Quiero que el teclado se cierre siempre que haga clic fuera de el, da igual si lo hago en un `TextView`, `ImageView`... o un lugar vacío.

Esto me ha funcionado pero tengo que hacer doble clic si lo hago encima de `ScrollView`:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.
            INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    return true;
}
```

¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

`clase`:

```
public class Prueba extends AppCompatActivity implements SimpleGestureListener {

    TextView TextView1;
    GestosActivity detector;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.prueba);

        // Oculta teclado al iniciar la Activity
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

        TextView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView1);

        // gestos
        detector = new GestosActivity(this, this);


        // cierra teclado al hacer clic en TextView1
        TextView1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindow().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
                return false;
            }
        });

    }

    // gestos

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
        this.detector.onTouchEvent(me);
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(me);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwipe(int direction) {
        switch (direction) {
            case GestosActivity.SWIPE_DOWN:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Sin función de momento", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case GestosActivity.SWIPE_UP:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Sin función de momento", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
}
```

`Layout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/base_añadir"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="#f4f4f4">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="top|center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextNombre"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text="Name" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

**EDITO1:**

```
public class Prueba extends AppCompatActivity implements SimpleGestureListener {

    TextView TextView1;
    GestosActivity detector;
    EditText editTextNombre;
    View view;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.prueba);

        // Oculta teclado al iniciar la Activity
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

        editTextNombre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextNombre);
        TextView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView1);

        // gestos
        detector = new GestosActivity(this, this);


editTextNombre.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(!hasFocus) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
});

    }

    // gestos

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
        this.detector.onTouchEvent(me);
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(me);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwipe(int direction) {
        switch (direction) {
            case GestosActivity.SWIPE_DOWN:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Sin función de momento", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case GestosActivity.SWIPE_UP:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Sin función de momento", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

puedes hacer lo mismo que tu codigo pero cuando el edittext pierda el foco. Cuando haces click en el se despliega el teclado y obtiene el foco asi que cuando haces click fuera de el, sea donde sea, pierde el foco y por tanto podria ocultar el teclado. Algo asi:

```
NombreDeTuEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(!hasFocus) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
});
```

Ya me dirás si te funciona.

Aunque como ultimo recurso y mas sucio, siempre puedes poner ese código en todos tus controles para que al pulsar en cualquiera de ella se cierre el keyboard.

Saludos.

Comment: No me ha funcionado, no hace nada al hacer clic fuera del teclado, se queda abierto, he añadido a la pregunta como queda la clase con lo que me comentas, por si ves que hago algo mal, gracias @Curro

Comment: Debugea la app y comprueba que al hacer click en el edittext este coge el focus y que al hacer click fuera lo pierde. La clave va a estar ahi, seguramente no lo esta haciendo como queremos y no funciona del todo bien.

Comment: El problema es que no coge el focus @Curro

Comment: Vale, en ese caso lo que puedes hacer es ocultar el teclado en el evento onclicklistener del layout principal de tu xml, "@+id/base_añadir". Le estableces este evento onclicklistener y ahi es donde ocultas el teclado. Espero haberme explicado jejeje

Comment: Sí, eso ya lo había probado y funciona, pero claro, tengo que añadir uno para cada `TextView`, `EditText` ... Y por eso quería saber si hay alguna forma más "limpia" y al hacer clic en cualquier sitio se cierre, sino, pues tendré que hacer esto. @Curro

Comment: No te hace falta para cada elemento, con que lo hagas para el layout base de tu xml es suficiente pues hagas click donde lo hagas siempre sera detectado por este layout, en tu caso es un absolutelayout.

Comment: En este caso no es así, si hago clic en un `TextView` por ejemplo, no se cierra, solamente si hago clic en un hueco blanco, debo añadir otro onclicklistener a ese `TextView` y así con todos los elementos

Comment: Vale vale, ahora te entiendo mejor. Una pregunta, me decias que el problema es que no coge el foco, ¿pero al cargar la vista ya te aparece el teclado o solo cuando haces click en el edittext?, lo digo porque puedes forzar que un elemento coja el foco con requestfocus(). De todos modos la mejor opcion es poner en tu xml esto en el edittext android:focusable="true" para que coja el foco y entonces lo que te dije antes si deberia funcionar, el setonfocuschangelistener.

Comment: Tampoco me ha funcionado, finalmente voy a utilizar la solución que hemos comentado antes que aunque sea más "sucia" funciona correctamente! Añádela a la respuesta y la marco somo solución. Gracias!

Comment: Editada la respuesta. Siento que no hayamos encontrado la solucion perfecta. Hasta la proxima.